# is it possible for 2 different apps to use the same camera simultaneously?

Tags: android

I'd like to be able to use the video stream from the camera (or even a few frames per second) while another app is also using the camera. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Access to a camera is exclusive.

See the [Camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#release-camera), which says:

> If your application does not properly release the camera, all
>   subsequent attempts to access the camera, including those by your own
>   application, will fail and may cause your or other applications to be
>   shut down.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android dev guide, the answer is no. Usually when you start another camera app, you have to release camera in onPause() of the previous camera app. Otherwise an exception will be thrown. But why don't you try to use different camera? If one app is using back-facing camera, another one can use front-facing camera. On Samsung's galaxy 4, there's a camera mode called dual-shot. running different camera simultaneously seems to be no problem.